# Compare two DB tables and hide existing items

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I'm creating shopping cart and I'm having one problem: When someone orders an item I need to hide that item from printed MySQL DB items list (stored in table `items`) if this item is already bought. (That other users can not add this items to cart if someone already did that earlier and bought it.) Bought items are stored in other MySQL table `orders`. So somehow need to compare these two tables and filtrate this items from goods list which are ordered. Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

Travesty's answer, using a subquery is good. Another way would be using a join:

```
SELECT items.* FROM items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders
ON items.item_id = orders.item_id 
WHERE orders.item_id IS NULL -- only those which had no join
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure may need revising. The way that inventory systems are usually structured is that there is an items table that has a quantity (int type) column. This column should contain the amount of available inventory. You should then fill that number to match the inventory you have. If someone buys this item you should deduct the amount they bought. This way you don't have to create a new row for every piece of item that you have in stock. In your UI you should display the inventory you have in stock. (Items where the quantity column is greater than 0)

Comment: I agree with this. Seems much more flexible this way, so you don't have to have two entries in your `items` table just because you have two of the same exact item.